# How to read attributes from an arff file from scratch in java?

Tags: java, arff

I'm trying to read an arff file from scratch for this assignment. I feel like I'm doing it wrong. So like for example let's say I have this line

```
@attribute 'habitat' { 'd', 'g', 'l', 'm', 'p', 'u', 'w'}
```

I want to check if it's an attribute, then take the attribute name, and then add the instances to a list. So far I'm doing this. (st is the current line that i'm reading from the file)

```
st=st.replaceAll("'", "");
String[] token = st.split(" ");
if(token[0].trim().equals("@attribute")) {
   Attribute a=new Attribute(token[1]);
}
```

I'm not sure how to read the instances, since I split it according to spaces, the instances were split wrong. I feel like I'm going about reading this file wrong
This is my attribute class

```
public class Attribute {
public String name;
public LinkedList<Instance> instanceList=new LinkedList<Instance>();
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what is `Instance`

Comment: It's what the attribute can be, so here its the: 'd', 'g', 'l', 'm', 'p', 'u', 'w', you can assume the linkedlist is a list of strings for simplicity

Comment: Ok, I have a solution check here https://www.ideone.com/RjygYE

Comment: results() is not a method in the pattern's class?

Comment: The solution should work from Java9+

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do it :

your Attribute class

```
class Attribute {
    private String name;
    private LinkedList<String> instanceList;

    public Attribute(String name, LinkedList<String> instanceList) {
        this.name = name;
        this.instanceList = instanceList;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public LinkedList<String> getInstanceList() {
        return instanceList;
    }

    public void setInstanceList(LinkedList<String> instanceList) {
        this.instanceList = instanceList;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Attribute{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", instanceList=" + instanceList +
                '}';
    }
}
```

your main class :

```
     String str = "@attribute 'habitat' { 'd', 'g', 'l', 'm', 'p', 'u', 'w'}";
     Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("@attribute '(.*?)' \\{\\s*(.*?)\\s*\\}");
     List<Attribute> list = new ArrayList<>();
     // in case you would like to ignore case sensitivity,
     // you could use this statement:
     // Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s+", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
     Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
     // check all occurance
     while (matcher.find()) {
                list.add(new Attribute(matcher.group(1),
                        new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(matcher.group(2).replaceAll("[',]", "").trim().split("\\s+"))))
         );
            }
     System.out.println(list);
```

output :

```
[Attribute{name='habitat', instanceList=[d, g, l, m, p, u, w]}]
```

Comment: Nice you make it without Java9 :) +1